# How do I append a file to the start of a destination file without an intermediary file?

Tags: powershell, merge, append

I want to append the file toppart_ABC.txt (containing 'ABC') to the start of destinationfile_DEF.txt (containing 'DEF') without an intermediary file.

If I try

```
Add-Content -Path .\destinationfile_DEF.txt -Value (Get-Content .\toppart_ABC.txt)
```

This changes the right file, destinationfile_DEF.txt, but has wrong content - it puts the text at the bottom i.e. defabc

If I try

```
Add-Content -Path .\toppart_ABC.txt -Value (Get-Content .\destinationfile_DEF.txt)
```

This changes the wrong file toppart_ABC.txt, but has the right content i.e. abcdef

Ideally looking for a one liner, but not vital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't opposed to just rewriting the file, you can just do a `Set-Content` after retrieving both file contents:

```
Set-Content -Path .\destinationfile_DEF.txt -Value (Get-Content .\toppart_ABC.txt,.\destinationfile_DEF.txt)
```

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want to use the disk to recreate the new file, you can use memory and write it to disk in one go. There's no way to tell the system to prepend data to a file. Files (and disks) do not work that way.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, yes wanted to reuse the  original file instead of having to create a 3rd file.